# Asymmetric partial matching of text strings between two dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, string-matching

I have two dataframes:

- df1 is based on survey responses and includes a non-restricted field for users to add their location in the UK (or refuse to do so) formatted as so (not real data):

| Name | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | London/Liverpool |
| Bob | Manchester |
| Jim | No |
| David | I am based in Cardiff |

I have another dataframe  (df2) that is a single column list of UK cities and towns, like so:

| city |
| --- |
| Manchester |
| Cardiff |
| London |
| Brighton |
| Nottingham |

What I want to do is write code that will:

- Loop through df1
- For each entry in the location column, scan df2 and if ANY of the cities in df2 are exactly replicated in df1, add a new column(s) to df 1 pulling out the first match like so:

| Name | Location | Location_precise |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | London, or Brighton | London |
| Bob | Manchester | Manchester |
| Jim | No | - |
| David | I am based in Cardiff | Cardiff |

I can then use the location_precise column for further analysis with standardised names. What's tripping me up with regular left_join/lapply functions is that I want to allow partial matching in one direction (if a city in df2 is partially contained in df1) but NOT in the other direction (if an answer in df1$location is part of a city in df2, e.g. 'no' and 'nottingham' in the above example.

I don't know how to adapt regular dplyr functions to this because there is no common identifier in the two datasets - and therefore every join attempt ends in various errors. I am otherwise completely at my wits' end; I have tried using grep:

df1$location_precise <- lapply(df1$Location, grep, df2$city,value=T)

But this doesn't pick up partial matches without whitespace, like 'London/Glasgow'

I've also tried agrep, but this falsely identifies partial matches, like 'No' = 'Nottingham', and still doesn't pick up many other partial matches

Comment: `str_extract()` from the stringr package should do this easily https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html; basically do a `mutate(Location_precise =str_extract(Location, reference_df$cities)`

Comment: I get the following error: error in `str_extract()`:
! Can't recycle `string` (size 104) to match `pattern` (size 112). df1 is 104 rows, and my reference list of cities is 112, so I'm clearly applying something incorrectly here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember to place a reproducible example.

I have taken your tables (df1 and df2) and added an extra case to both:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:6], 
                  Location = c("London/Liverpool", 
                               "London/Glasgow",
                               "I born in Manchester",
                               "I am from Chester",
                               "No",
                               "I am based in Cardiff"))

df2 <- data.frame(city = c("Manchester",
                           "Cardiff",
                           "London",
                           "Chester",
                           "Glasgow",
                           "Brighton",
                           "Nottingham"))


df1$Location_precise <- strsplit(x = df1$Location, split = "[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]") |> 
  
  lapply(FUN = \(locations, patterns){
    
    sapply(X = locations, FUN = \(loc){
      patterns[sapply(X = sprintf("^%s$", patterns), 
                      FUN = grepl, x = loc, ignore.case = TRUE)]  
    })
  }, patterns = df2$city) |> 
  
  lapply(FUN = unlist) |> 
  
  sapply(FUN = \(x) if(length(x) == 0) "-" else if(length(x) == 1) x else if(length(x) > 1) paste(x, collapse = ", "))
```

The output:

```
> df1
  Name              Location Location_precise
1    A      London/Liverpool           London
2    B        London/Glasgow  London, Glasgow
3    C  I born in Manchester       Manchester
4    D     I am from Chester          Chester
5    E                    No                -
6    F I am based in Cardiff          Cardiff
```

It may not be the most elegant example, but you could try it and we'll refine it. For cases where there is more than one match, I have it show all matches and separate them with commas.

**UPDATE:**
I have extended the steps and this time it is now able to identify complete words. However, when I talk about identifying **complete words**, I mean that the script now cuts and searches in each word of each element of `df1$Location`. For this you must keep in mind that 1) a (complete) word is defined as a set of characters contained either between two blanks or between two punctuation marks (check what characters are included in `[:space:]` and `[:punct:]` in this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing)), 2) because of the above, if there is a *Man-chester*, *Man,chester*, *Man/chester*, etc., the script will assign *Chester* to it and 3) this is computationally somewhat more expensive (because the search is done word by word), so if you plan to apply it over millions of values it may be slow.

Comment: This works very well, thank you very much. I also appreciate the polite feedback re: reproducible examples, I will make sure to take more care in future. One last niggle - is it possible to partial match, but only on whole words separated by spaces? At present, the output will always return both 'Manchester' and 'Chester' every time it finds the former

Comment: @EdwardBlackburn I have made some changes (including cases in the reproducible example) to cover the full word search.

Comment: This works wonderfully. Once again I really appreciate the clear explanation and elegant solution!